# android development: device sdk is lower then minSdk

Tags: android, sdk

I am new to app development, and I am facing a problem trying to debug my app on a real device.

I bought a new phone, I didn't connect it yet to the internet nor anything. just opened it, set it to a developer mode so I can plug it to my computer and debug apps, and that all.

then, on my laptop, when trying to run the app with android studio through the device, t tells me that the device is incompatible, and that the:
minSdk(API 8) > deviceSdk (API 1).
how do I update my device SDK? can I update it through the laptop with the usb? can it really be just API 1? even though it's a new phone? (and a good one)

- In the state of the device, it also says that the device is Unauthorized if it means anything

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Enable Developers Options by hitting 7 times on:

  - Stock Android: Settings > About phone > Build number
  - Samsung Galaxy S5: Settings > About device > Build number
  - LG G3: Settings > About phone > Software information > Build number
  - HTC One (M8): Settings > About > Software information > More > Build number
- Enable MTP in device:

> Settings-> Storage-> Three dots on top right->USB computer
>   connection->Enable "Media device (MTP)"

Also be sure your device is visible in your system (has good drivers installed). 
Go to platform-tools and type: `adb devices` - your device should be listed there.

Comment: Did it and also did "revoke" and then unlug the phone, and plug again and it worked. thanks!